# Zitat aus dem Film "Die Fälscher"

Tags: translation, english-to-german, german-to-english, french

Ich suche nach einem Zitaten aus dem Film ["Die Fälscher"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_F%C3%A4lscher).

[Die Englische Version](https://subslikescript.com/movie/The_Counterfeiters-813547) lautet:

> A Jew... but he died like a man!

Meiner Meinung nach, musste es etwas sein wie:

> Ein Jude... aber er starb wie ein Mensch

Eigentlich möchte ich wissen, ob das Wort *Mensch* benutzt wird, um dann eine [eine Frage auf French.SE](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/51131/9870) beantworten zu können.

Comment: Ich kann keinen Text in der deutschen Fassung finden, aber ich würde es mit "Mann" übersetzen.

Comment: Die Zeile befindet sich in der [DWDS-Nutzungsdatenbank](https://www.dwds.de/r/?q=Jude+%26%26+sterben+%26%26+Mann&corpus=untertitel&date-start=1916&date-end=2014&format=full&sort=date_desc&limit=50): "Ein Jude, aber der starb wie ein Mann."

Comment: @RDBury: Das wäre m.M.n. eine gute Antwort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Man kann die deutschen Untertitel für diesen Film hier herunterladen: https://dl.opensubtitles.org/de/download/sub/3160782

Man erhält eine zip-Datei, die nach dem Entpacken zwei Dateien enthält, die trotz der Endungen .nfo und .srt ganz normale Texdateien sind, die man mit jedem Texteditor öffnen kann. Die Datei empire-faelscher-xvid.srt enthält sämtliche deutschen Untertitel dieses Films. Es kommt darin nur ein einziges Mal das Wort *»starb«* vor. Es ist diese Stelle:

> 722
> 01:17:02,720 --> 01:17:06,190
> Ein Jude,
> aber der starb wie ein Mann.

Das gesucht Wort lautet also *»Mann«.* Das macht auch Sinn, denn es sollte nicht zum Ausdruck gebracht werden, dass er wie ein *Mensch,* also *menschlich* (sozial, barmherzig, lieb, entgegenkommend, besonnen, freundlich, ...) starb, sondern wie ein *Mann,* also *männlich* (tapfer, kämpferisch, heldenhaft, unbeugsam, loyal). (Vergleiche Synonyme zu [menschlich](https://synonyme.woxikon.de/synonyme/menschlich.php) und [männlich](https://synonyme.woxikon.de/synonyme/m%C3%A4nnlich.php).)

Comment: Unter dem Gesichtspunkt, dass die NS-Propaganda Juden bewusst entmenschlicht hat, um ihre Gräueltaten zu rechtfertigen oder zumindest leichter zu gestalten, wäre auch die andere Übersetzung denkbar gewesen,

Comment: @infinitezero: Den Satz sagt genau jener Nazi, der den jungen Mann wenige Augenblicke vorher ziemlich emotionslos im Hinterhof erschossen hat (Nazi: »Wie alt bist du eigentlich?« Karloff: »20« Nazi: »Und wo kommst du her?« Karloff: »Odessa« Nazi: »Odessa? Schön. Das Schwarze Meer ... Knie dich hin.« Dann kniet sich Karloff nieder, der Nazi zieht seine Pistole und erschießt Karloff. Einfach so, ohne jede Emotion. Mit derselben Routine und Gelassenheit mit der man jemandem eine Zigarette reichen würde. Wenig später ...

Comment: ...steht der Mörder in der Baracke der Juden, und sagte mit derselben Beiläufigkeit, mit der gerade einen Mord begangen hat, dass er Karloff erschießen musste weil er TBC hatte. Bei dieser Gelegenheit sagt der Nazi den besprochenen Satz. Es hätte da nicht gepasst, wenn der Mörder sein Opfer *»Mensch«* genannt hätte.